# SDL2 messed up image with manipulating pixels and SDL_UpdateTexture()

Tags: c, image, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a simple image viewer. I basically load an image into a surface and then create a texture from it.

At the end, I do the usual `SDL_RenderClear()`, `SDL_RenderCopy()` and `SDL_RenderPresent()` as per the [migration guide](http://wiki.libsdl.org/MigrationGuide).

This works fine, except that if I call `SDL_UpdateTexture()` before the 3 render calls above, I get a messed up image:

[image: Messed up image]

I am calling SDL_UpdateTexture() like this:

```
SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, image->pixels, image->pitch)
```

Where `image` is the surface I loaded for the image and `texture` is the texture I created from that. Attempts to vary the pitch result in differently messed up images. I also tried using a rect for the second parameter, but results are the same if the rect has the same dimensions as the image. If the dimensions are larger (e.g. same as the window), the update doesn't happen, but there are no errors.

The [full code](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9465&sid=39eba5d2d528057122bc8b7d6265edcf) is available.

I would like to manipulate pixels of the surface directly via `image->pixels` and then call `SDL_UpdateTexture()`, but just calling `SDL_UpdateTexture()` without any tampering is enough to mess things up.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with the pitch or the `SDL_Rect` parameters,
but there is another SDL function which might help:

```
SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
                                      SDL_Surface*  surface)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe try the following. It should replace any pink (r=255,g=0,b=255) pixels to be transparent. You would simply change the pixel32 manipulation to accommodate your needs.

```
SDL_Surface* image = IMG_Load(filename);

SDL_Surface* imageFomatted = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(image, 
                                                      SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
                                                      NULL);

texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
                            SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
                            SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                            imageFomatted->w, imageFomatted->h);

void* pixels = NULL;
int pitch = 0;

SDL_LockTexture(texture, &imageFomatted->clip_rect, &pixels, &pitch);

memcpy(pixels, imageFomatted->pixels, (imageFomatted->pitch * imageFomatted->h));

int width   = imageFomatted->w;
int height  = imageFomatted->h;

Uint32* pixels32    = (Uint32*)pixels;
int     pixelCount  = (pitch / 4) * height;

Uint32 colorKey     = SDL_MapRGB(imageFomatted->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
Uint32 transparent  = SDL_MapRGBA(imageFomatted->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00);

for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
  if (pixels32[i] == colorKey) {
    pixels32[i] = transparent;
  }
}

SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);

SDL_FreeSurface(imageFormatted);
SDL_FreeSurface(image);

pixels = NULL;
pitch = 0;
width = 0;
height = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's going bonkers on the memcpy, but runs if you replace image->pitch with just pitch. I commented out from the colorKey line until the end of the for loop since formattedSurf isn't defined anywhere. I can't seem to use pixels without crashing the program.

Comment: @Gigi sorry I made a couple of mistakes as I was adapting my code to fit with yours so missed a couple of variable names. Could you try the full code again (including the memcopy) I think this may have been messed up by not converting the surface format before creating the texture so I have added this.

Comment: You missed the declaration of texture and also have a typo in imageFormatted (missing 'r') - so the SDL_FreeSurface(imageFormatted) is inconsistent. After fixing those, I still get crashes on memcpy. Can you maybe try testing the code before posting it?

Comment: @Gigi This code is tested and does work as I use the same method. Sorry for the errors with variable typos but those were easily corrected. What is the actual crash you are getting on memcpy as that is the main concern.